# Django + MongoDB using mongodb-engine gives multipleobjectreturned

Tags: django, session, mongodb, pymongo

when i access localhost:8000/admin gives me the error 
'MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/
get() returned more than one Session -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'session_key': 'ee5a8be487352e42a89f962ee4ab22a6', 'expire_date__gt': datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 8, 5, 38, 36, 645053)}'

if access the mongodb and delete one of the rows in the collection django_session it works, but after awhile gives me the same error because it was created another document in the collection django_session

update : even in the browser i deleted the cookie that stored the session id then i was able to run the page smoothly. then when i refresh or click on the link i get the multiple object returned error.

is this a problem with the mongodb-engine for django that tries to add session ids for every page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

By default, MongoDB creates a unique index on the `_id` field. However, it looks like you are using the `session_key` field, which is not unique by default, which may explain how you're getting two entries.

Take a look at the indexes that are in use: `./mongo localhost:8000/admin --eval "db.system.indexes.find()"` and see if this isn't just an index problem. Information about creating unique indexes is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes).

You may also want to take a look at the code that creates the `django_session` documents. They may be doing something "not quite right" that's causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the author in charge of django-mongodb-engine who had missed out adding django.contrib libraries( Admin library of django belongs in it.) to the test. He added the fix by which now you can access admin without getting the mulipleobjectreturned error.

this is the commit that fixes the issue (https://github.com/django-mongodb-engine/mongodb-engine/issues/53) : https://github.com/django-mongodb-engine/mongodb-engine/commit/a0ab9c3f7c378828c2800b8f62f67c8e21255835

Hope this helps someone else.